# Puppet agent returning error on windows 7

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am new to puppet and have a very little knowledge of it. I have just started working on it and trying to configure windows machine as an agent.
While trying to run agent process it is giving following error.

> Error: Could not request certificate: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Even though servers are in communication. I have tried to google it but didn't success ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the firewall was active on the master machine and which is why agent machine was not able to communicate master machine.